# What are these 'cabochon' tiles called in English

Tags: tile

I'm looking to source some of these tiles which alternate large and small tiles in a matrix. The French name is cabochon, but that is not proving useful in the UK to shop for this style of alternating big/small square/octagon arrangement. Obviously the size can vary, I'm looking for about 20-30cm for the larger part of the pattern rather than a small mosaic.

[image]

Comment: What size are those squares?  If an inch or two "mosaic tile" will help,  If larger, not sure.

Answer (score 6):

"Octagon and dot". Not very elegant a term, eh?